# How do you get a Kubernetes pod's name from its IP address?

Tags: kubernetes

How do I get a pod's name from its IP address?  What's the magic incantation of `kubectl` + `sed`/`awk`/`grep`/etc regardless of where `kubectl` is invoked?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### Example:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
alpine-3835730047-ggn2v            1/1       Running   0          5d        10.22.19.69   ip-10-35-80-221.ec2.internal
```

#### get pod name by IP

```
kubectl get --all-namespaces  --output json  pods | jq '.items[] | select(.status.podIP=="10.22.19.69")' | jq .metadata.name
"alpine-3835730047-ggn2v"
```

#### get container name by IP

```
kubectl get --all-namespaces  --output json  pods | jq '.items[] | select(.status.podIP=="10.22.19.69")' | jq .spec.containers[].name
"alpine"
```

Answer (score 50):

Can be done without additional tools, just kubectl is enough:

```sh
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=:metadata.name --no-headers=true --field-selector status.podIP=<pod-ip-address-goes-here>
```

Comment: Works great.  Including `kubectl get`'s `--all-namespaces` flag like in the other answers is a helpful variation (e.g. checking IPs logged in a CNI plugin log file).

Answer (score 13):

Another way to get pod name by ip address is like this:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide | grep 10.2.6.181

jenkins       jenkins-2-7d6d7fd99c-9xgkx                                                2/2     Running            3          12d   10.2.6.181      ip.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal    <none>
```

In this example, the pod name is "jenkins-2-7d6d7fd99c-9xgkx" for ip address "10.2.6.181".

Answer (score 0):

```
k get pods -A -o wide -o custom-columns=:metadata.namespace,:metadata.name,:status.podIP
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.